# React Client to Laravel Backend - Mail is not being Sent

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, email

Firstly, I am pretty new in ReactJS and have no prior experience in Laravel, so the question may seem irrelevant or pointless, so any correction is appreciated. I am trying to send an email via using a form on the client side. When I submit the form, the response seems 200 OK and all the data is being sent. But I don't get an email in the account which I am supposed to. Here is the sendMail function on the client, and backend function which is supposed to get post request and send an email with the data in request.

FRONTEND

```
    const sendMail = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
      const reservationdetail = JSON.stringify(allValues);
      axios
        .post('http://panel.xyz.com/api/send-reservation', {
          reservationdetail: reservationdetail
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        })
        .then(function () {});
      $('.reservation-tab-area').addClass('d-none');
      dispatch(changePage(3));
    }
```

BACKEND

```
     public function addReservation(Request $request)
        {
    
            $jsondata = $request;
            Reservation::create(['reservationdetail' => $jsondata->reservationdetail]);
    
            $reservationdetail= $jsondata->reservationdetail;
            $email = 'rezervasyon@xyz.com';
    
            $rezerve= json_decode($reservationdetail);
           
            $offer = [
                'title' => 'İnfo Contact',
                'name' => $rezerve->name,
                'surname' => $rezerve->surname,
                'cityselect' => $rezerve->cityselect,
                'phone' => $rezerve->phone,
                'mail' => $rezerve->mail,
                'message' => $rezerve->message,
                'deliveryCity' => $rezerve->deliveryCity,
                'returnCity' => $rezerve->returnCity,
                'contactViaEmail' => $rezerve->contactViaEmail,
                'contactViaPhone' => $rezerve->contactViaPhone,
                'contactViaWhatsapp' => $rezerve->contactViaWhatsapp,
                'total' => $rezerve->totalAmount,
                'enddate' => $rezerve->endDate,
                'startdate' => $rezerve->startDate,
                'carname' => $rezerve->carselect->name,
                'carclass' => $rezerve->carselect->class,
            ];
           
            Mail::to($email)->send(new OfferMail($offer));
    
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure the `$email` should be `rezervasyon@xyz.com` not `reservation@xyz.com`?

Comment: Also I notice you don't have a `url` in the `$offer` and all the examples I've found do.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Email is correct, no problem there. So you think the problem is not about the structure but about the data?.  Can you please explain what type of url should the data contain?

Comment: I'm looking at an example (which looks minimalistic but still has a `url` in it). https://remotestack.io/send-email-in-laravel-with-markdown-template-example/

Comment: You could just set the url to `https://www.google.com` just to test it out.

Comment: Also I notice that `send-reservation` in the post url doesn't match the name of the function (`addReservation`). Shouldn't be a problem if you've wired it up that way but might be worth checking you're hitting the right endpoint.

Comment: Yes, I have wired them up, no problem there. Now, added the url in offer and making another test.

Comment: If that doesn't work, try adding `return response('Hello World', 200)->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');` in `addReserveration()` and comment out all the other code in that function. Then you can try again and if the response is 'Hello World', you can be sure you're hitting the right endpoint.

Comment: Yaayyy, it worked. Thank you soo much. I didn't think that I could find a way to fix this. Yes, you saved me a lot of time and effort. Thank you again, you are great helper. Adding some random URL was the solution.

Comment: Excellent. Glad to hear that did the trick.